# Настройка Live Reload в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как подключить плагин Live Reload к Sublime Text 3, чтобы реагировал на изменения в хроме? Вроде бы соединение идет, но ничего на странице не меняется.

Comment: Вопрос актуален? Как именно устанавливали? Можно много информации в интернете найти, в том числе [на русском](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUc-1c9KOq0). В случае неудачи пробовали ли [альтернативы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12829369/5951529)? Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку! 
Нет, вопрос уже не актуален. Все нашел, были глюки с виндовс